# Code Igniter - Best way to detect browser

Tags: php, codeigniter

I want to shunt all browsers of a certain age off to their own page. What is the best method for doing this? Perhaps some JS in the header that is wrapped in :

```
 <!--[if lte IE 7 ]>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.location = "/unsupported-browser/";
    </script>
    <![endif]-->
```

Shouldn't the above send the browser to: http://example.com/unsupported-browser/ where I have a basic controller and view to handle it? Is it that simple?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Do this in php instead. Use the [user_agent class](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/user_agent.html) and [redirect](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html#footer) to that page.

But more importantly, why don't you allow IE users access to your site? Is it due to CSS or something else?

**Code:**

```
$this->load->helper('url');
$this->load->library('user_agent');

if ($this->agent->browser() == 'Internet Explorer' and $this->agent->version() <= 7)
    redirect('/unsupported-browser');
```

**Edit:**

As mentioned; if you want this over your entire site, run this in **MY_Controller** and make sure to add `$this->uri->segment(1) != 'unsupported-browser'` as an extra condition to avoid redirect loops.

Comment: OP said shift to a different page not deny access, but user_agent is what id do

Comment: Based on example it looks like they will be sent to a page saying "This site is not available in your browser, please upgrade it"

Comment: yeah you are right, not a good thing to do but often im tempted

Comment: Yeah, I hear you man. I'd prefer if everyone used latest mozilla and webkit browser so I always knew what my users gained as a result. It all depends on how you many on the internet you wish your service to be functional for. Think if Facebook had a /unsupported-browser page, for instance :)

Comment: For some reason this redirect always goes to: mysite.com/?/unsupported-browser Any idea why the ? is getting added to the path?

Comment: Troubleshoot it. Echo `$this->agent->browser()` and see if it's 'Internet Explorer'.

Comment: If You use this code in MY_Controller.php you will have redirect loop. Try to add `$this->uri->segment(1) != 'unsupported-browser'` into IF statement.

Comment: Yepp, that's true. Updated answer.

Answer (score 2):

Download library from http://mobiledetect.net

Put Mobile_Detect.php in to 'libraries'

inside main controller

```
public function index() {
    $this -> load -> library('Mobile_Detect');
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    if ($detect->is('Chrome') || $detect->is('iOS')) {
        // whatever you wanna do here.
    }
}
```

Find documentation on https://dwij.net/mobile-os-detection-in-php-codeigniter