# Only allow access to the site for HTML5 Users

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want my site written in HTML5 and CSS3 to be only accessable for HTML 5 Users. So if a user is using a legacy browser just like IE 7 or something i want to make my site to be blank and show a notification, which says for example "Please update your browser to use this application". 
I already tried the modernizr plugin but it only supports feature detection and thats not what i want. I want to know if the users browser is able to display HTML5 and CSS3 correctly.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: There is no such thing as HTML5 making this question unanswerable.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20386610/block-older-browsers-without-blocking-bots-googlebot-bingbot-etc

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15275463/how-to-block-ie8-and-down

Comment: Why was my comment deleted? Simply refered to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6731303/how-to-detect-html-5-compatibility-in-browser

Comment: @davidkonrad When closing as dupe it is automatically converted to the header of the question

Comment: OK, thank you for clarification. Didnt vote for close, however, just wrote "possible duplicate xxx", wasnt sure - but thank you for responding again.